# Setting the Differnet Stages with SVN Tortoise

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am working on the system with the development environment setting controlled by SVN Tortoise. In the Current System, I work on development, commit my files to SVN and update the live to shift the changes to live server. My Goal is to check my changes on some staging environment before moving it to live server. So, my SVN developed environment should work in the following order.

1) I do changes on development and commit my file to SVN stage 1.
2) I update the staging server to check my changes.
3) If changes are fine, I commit the staging files to SVN stage 2.
4) SVN stage 2 is linked to Production. So, I update the production to move my changes to live.

That is what I want to set up on my system? Is it possible with SVN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if i understand your question. 
but I am assuming that you need something between your development environment and live server (that is what you are calling **SVN Stage**).
I believe, there is nothing like that.
You can't create any stagging in SVN.
The files (you comited from your development server) will go to your production server.
(without any medium in-between to which you can access)

But,
You can commit files from your development server to another development server (that will be your Stage 1).
The server at Stage 1 will have another SVN setup here.
Now,
when you commit files from Stage 1, your files will be comited to your live server (or may be to another Stage)

In simple words, you may link your Development server, staging server and live server.
Files commited from Development server will go to Staging server and files commited from Staging server will go to your live server.
(But you will need antoher SVN setup on you Staging server ).

**NOTE :**
You may want to use **"jenkins"** as reommended by **@gbjbaanb**

Comment: Thanks @malikGee I have searched on the base of your answer and I get a lot of help in setting my system.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're saying but.. here;'s my interpretation:

you want to use a Continuous Integration server (I highly recommend [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)). When you check in your changes to the dev repository, Jenkins will notice, will check them out and perform whatever checks you have to them, then it can perform other tasks - such as copying the files to the production server.